# Why Thread faster than Parallel.Foreach to open OracleConnection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, oracle, ado.net, task-parallel-library

I have 2 pieces of code as follows, one use Thread and one use Parallel.Foreach

**Thread**

```
foreach (var i in new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24 })
    new Thread(GET_DATA).Start(i);
```

**Parallel**

```
Parallel.Foreach(new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24 }, GET_DATA);
```

with method GET_DATA

```
void GET_DATA(object state) {
    var x = (int)state;

    using (var conn = new OracleConnection(cs[x])) {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand()) {
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from dual";
            var dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
        }
    }
}
```

and cs is connection string array for 25 Oracle Database

I use `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6200U CPU @ 2.30GHz` with `16GB RAM`, OracleConnection in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess library from nuget.

**At first time, when no Connection Pool is created**

- `Thread approach`: all thread stop at 3 to 5 seconds after run
- `Parallel approach`: parallel stop at 12 to 15 seconds after run

**At next times, results of the 2 approaches are similar because Connection Pools are created.**

I guess parallel running on single-core should be nearly 4 times slower than thread, can anyone explain it?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/ It is official, System.Data.OracleClient is deprecated

Comment: How do you know it's faster? You never *wait* for it to finish. Running multiple commands in parallel won't make your code run *faster* either. It can make it go a *lot* slower if the queries block each other. If you have a performance problem with data insertion use the appropriate bulk import mechanism.

Comment: @Panagiotis: In my real code I have a StopWatch to count running time and WaitHandle to wait all Thread run. I use Parallel / Thread to retrieve data from 25 sources, it's faster than run sequentially many times.

Comment: How about only a *single* execution that gets the values as parameters? The database disks aren't going to run faster if you send multiple queries instead of one. The network bandwidth will remain the same. On the other hand, filling a *DataTable* hurts performance. Doing it in parallel, hurts more.

Comment: Due to the potential asynchronous nature of the thread calls you should prolly post the full waiting code for the Thread code - just to make sure your waiting code is actually legit.

Comment: @MartinLeung How many rows do you want to return? You could use a microORM like Dapper to use multiple values in an `IN (@ids)` clause and map the results directly to the objects you want. The database will be able to optimize the single query with `IN (1,2,4,5..)` and return the results as fast as possible.

Comment: @MartinLeung finally, if you have a *lot* of rows (tens of thousands) the fastest way would be to use Oracle's export mechanism to export the data to a local file and read it from the application.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: But it's faster, my test use select * from dual for nearly zero DB disk read, very small bandwitdth. It slow at open connection not slowly infrastructure factor.

Comment: @MartinLeung that doesn't test data transfer speeds. What you measured is *only* opening the first connection. A connection that *will* be reused due to connection pooling. The test doesn't actually mean anything.

Comment: @MartinLeung in fact, as others suggested, this should be an asynchronous operation. You could issue multiple OpenAsync calls and await all of them without creating *any* thread. Just collect all the returned `Task` objects in an array and use `await Task.WhenAll()` on it.

Comment: If your customer use your program, first time they click a button to view report, they wait and wait. Oh fifteen seconds for 25 lines, and they tell with your boss that the program is slow. You will understand first time meaning. In my work, I tested it quite thoroughly, no problem for this approach. Of course, there are many ways you can improve its speed, as well, but in most cases the use of a library is still acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first example you spawn 24 threads, and they will each start by waiting on an I/O operation (establishing socket connection to database) to complete.

In the second example you are using an unknown number of threads (depends on the number of cores, and degree of parallelization settings) to process a list of 24 items. Each thread will process a subset of the items in serial.

Since the operation is not CPU-bound in your process, but rather dependent on external processes (I/O to the database, operations on the database, etc.), the `Parallel.Foreach` will waste a lot of time waiting for one task to finish before starting the next.

**Example**

X is the completion of an operation, time goes vertically, threads go horizontally.

When using 24 threads:

```
1 2 3 ... 24   Time
| | |      |    |
| | |      |    |
| | |      |    |
| | |      |    |
| | |      |    |
X X X      X    V
```

When using 4 threads to process 24 items:

```
1 2 3 4   Time
| | | |    |    
| | | |    |    
| | | |    |    
X X X X    |    
| | | |    |
| | | |    |
| | | |    |
X X X X    |
| | | |    |
| | | |    |
| | | |    |
X X X X    |
. . . .    |
. . . .    |
. . . .    V
```

Comment: So the expectation here could be that 24 threads on 4 'logical' cores would end up getting slowed down by potential context switching or CPU scheduling? Unless the code is *really* I/O bound

Comment: @odyss-jii: Really. why Parallel use 4 threads, why it not use 24 threads or more.

Comment: @MartinLeung By default most parallel libraries use the number of your CPU cores, because usually tasks are CPU bound. There is no AI to determine what your task is going to do or how else would it know what amount of parallel task is best suited for your problem? There are some ways, but usually it adds unnecessary complexity to the parallel framework if you want dynamic thread scaling or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```
Parallel.Foreach(new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24 }, GET_DATA);
```

Please also add this to `Parallel.Foreach` to make the two samples use the same number of thread.

```
new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 24 }
```

As for normal `foreach`, This will wait for all threads to finish before exiting the loop

```
foreach (var i in new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24 })
    new Thread(GET_DATA).Start(i);
```

I believe you will get the same result if you wait for all thread to be finish.

Comment: My code have wait but I post sample for easy to understand
          var lt = new List<WaitHandle>();
            foreach (var x in states)
            {
                lt.Add((ManualResetEvent)x[5]);
                new Thread(GET_DATA).Start(x);
            }
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(lt.ToArray());

Comment: @MartinLeung Please don't add code in comments, it cannot be read easily.

Comment: Yes, thank for your comment, but your explain is not what I want.

Comment: @MartinLeung can you try to specify the number of thread for "Parallel.Foreach"? I updated my answer.

Comment: MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 24, I also used it, but nothing changed

Comment: @MartinLeung Did you try something like this: `Parallel.For(1, 24, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 24 }, GET_DATA)` ?

Comment: @xander: Why you think it better than Parallel.Foreach(new int [] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 24 }, GET_DATA);

Comment: It's not really better, but why would you create a list of 24 integers when `Parallel.For` has range parameters? Also that example shows how to use the `ParallelOptions`, because it didn't work for you.